# "With experience (in)"?

Tags: usage

When you describe you are someone with experience in or just simply experience?

> Looking for someone with experience *in* testing lab animals.

Or just simply

> Looking for someone with experience testing lab animals.

I've seen both and I prefer the one with "in",  but I'm not sure if one is better than the other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use *in* when saying *experience in [field]* and *with* when saying *experience with [task]*.

> We're looking for someone who has experience *with* testing lab animals.
>
> We're looking for someone who has experience *in* Laboratory Research.

However you can leave out the *with* in your example if you want, because it is implied.

> We're looking for someone who has experience testing lab animals.

Comment: One other option: you can also move the area of expertise in front of the word _experience_, as in: "We are looking for someone with C++ programming experience," or "We are looking for someone with animal testing experience in a laboratory setting."